# Calling 'centralised' C# code from Excel

Tags: c#, excel, dll

Is there an easy way of e.g. keeping a DLL full of procedures written in C# on a shared network folder, then calling stuff from that from Excel?

Multiple users might be calling stuff at any one time, don't know if that makes a difference or not.

The stuff I'm calling will need to pull data from the Excel sheet in question, faff around with it, sometimes return it to the sheet, sometimes do something else with it (raise an email in Outlook with some of said data in the subject and body, for example).

I want it on a shared drive because this stuff changes on a regular basis, so I'd rather avoid having to e.g. deploy a new add-in on all of the machines every time I update some code in the DLL.

At the moment we're still on Excel 2002/2003 (ugh), so if it's possible within that I'm laughing. If not, what version of Office would we need?

Thanks

Comment: While you probably **can** do this, there are some issues. Distributing it with an addon often means that you can deploy incrementally, which can be a real life-saver if an unintended bug crops up. That issue is compounded by the fact that you want to change the code often. Unhappy users leads to unhappy management, which leads to unhappy you.

Comment: This easy to do with VBA using a stub loader addin installed on the users PC that just opens the XLAM/XLL addin from a network share: but I don't know how to create a stub loader that loads COM/Automation addins

Answer (score 0):

I dont have answer to your question. 
If you are not interested in deploying this in users machine you could rather wrap that dll up in a simple WCF service and deploy that in a server.

Putting dll in shared folder might need some work along the security stuff like making the shared folder readonly avoiding others accessing it.